# Why is my code not rendering a list of table on my web page?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I have a model D100Generator with an incrementing primary key. I am trying to mimic the Django tutorial pt. 3, substituting a list of table names for the questions that should be rendered on the index.html page.  When I run the code, I get a `<ul>` bullet point, but no text. Is my `latest_table_list` not being populated? Or is it I'm calling the wrong thing?

I am very new to Python, web development and Stack Overflow, so forgive me if the formatting and explanation is poor on this.

I suspect I'm not calling the `table_name` field correctly, but nothing I've tried has been able to work.

I tried setting the line item for the list as:

```
<li><a href="/generators/{{ d100Generator.d_100_id }}/">{{ d100Generator.table_name }}</a></li>
```

and as:

`<li><a href="/generators/{{ d100Generator.id }}/">{{ d100Generator.table_name }}</a></li>`

Neither of which will help display as desired.

The D100Generator Model

```
class D100Generator(models.Model):
    d_100_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_of_interest = models.ForeignKey(FieldOfInterest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subreddit_post_id = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    module_id = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    generic_website_id = models.ForeignKey(GenericWebsite, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    table_name = models.CharField('table name', max_length=100)
    system = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    chart_type = models.CharField('Die used', max_length=15)
    chart_instructions = models.TextField('Chart instructions & explanation')
    roll_1 = models.TextField('1', blank=True, null=True)
    roll_2 = models.TextField('2', blank=True, null=True)
    roll_3 = models.TextField('3', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    roll_110 = models.TextField('110', blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.table_name
```

#Views.py Entry for Index

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import D100Generator

def index(request):
    latest_table_list = D100Generator.objects.order_by('-d_100_id')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_table_list': latest_table_list
    }
    return render(request, 'generators/index.html', context)
```

##Code on the index.html page itself

```
<h1>Welcome to Capstone Generators' homepage!</h1>
<br>
<h2>Recent topics added include:</h2>
<br>
<h2>Recent tables added include:</h2>
{% if latest_table_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for d_100_id in latest_table_list %}
        <li>{{ D100Generator.table_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No tables are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I have one table the has been manually added via the admin page, so the bulleted list should include the table name "Your elf learned over 25 years..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using loop variable `d_100_id` but you are trying to access table_name with `D100Generator`

So change this to:

```
{% for d_100_id in latest_table_list %}
        <li>{{ d_100_id.table_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and I was able to adapt it too.  
So d_100_id is set as a loop variable?  Why do I write d_100_id.table_name instead of D100Generator.table_name?

Comment: @brosengren you set `d_100_id` as a loop variable in  this line `{% for d_100_id in latest_table_list %}` so you need to use this loop variable not the model name